# Exportar registro como imagem no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, blob, longblob

Eu estou tentando exportar imagens de uma tabela que foram salvas em binário em um campo mediumblob para um diretório específico, eu tentei com a seguinte query:

```
SELECT FILE INTO OUTFILE "C:\\1.jpg" FROM imagem WHERE file_id = 1
```

Ele até cria o arquivo da imagem no C:, porém fica ilegível.

Detalhes:

- Versão do MySQL Server: 5.1
- Campo não está encriptado em base64.
- Se eu uso o save to file do SGBD ele exporta e abre a imagem normalmente.
- Usei a func HEX() para converter o binário em hexadecimal e este é parte do resultado:

`47494638396176062209F70000030304060609060906060A0908060709070A090A070B0B0B0704110A06110E0D110E0B1A0D110D0E1211100E0F110E`

Pesquisei bastante e não encontrei nenhum exemplo que fizesse via sql, eu precisaria dessa forma específica se for possível.

Comment: olá Cesar, se é `mysql` remova a tag de `sql-server`

Answer (score 0):

Para quem está com a mesma dificuldade que eu estive, segue a resolução:

```
SELECT FILE INTO DUMPFILE "C:\\1.jpg" FROM imagem WHERE file_id = 1
```

DumpFile trabalha melhor que IntFile para este fim.

Resolvido.